# Oracle error : Shutdown immediate error

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

```
echo $ORACLE_SID
YBRD
conn sys/hello as sysdba
SQL>shutdown immediate
```

Then I was waiting for it to shutdown for a couple of minutes. It didn't, so I closed my window.

Then I again logged in and it displayed:

```
ORACLE IMMEDIATE SHUTDOWN IN PROGRESS
```

Will it shutdown automatically by itself after a while?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will -- of course if it persistently refuses to you might have to kill the processes, and face instance recovery on restart.

Answer (score 2):

Normally it should happen quickly.
There could be large transactions that take a while to rollback, or a long running transaction that takes ages to end.

If the time is spent for the rollback, you could crash the instance with a good and solid kill -9 on the server procs and use parallel instance recovery. Normally this should not happen but parallel instance recovery can be quicker than a recovery by 1 process.

[see Oracle manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28273/rcmsynta045.htm)

Answer (score 0):

According to ["Shutdown Timeout"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/start003.htm#CIHDAGBD) section in Database Administrator's Guide, shutting down the database in any of the following modes may take up to one hour:

- Normal Mode
- Immediate Mode
- Transactional Mode

Shutdown in Abort Mode will bring your instance down in a short amount of time not allowing it to checkpoint (see ["Overview of Checkpoints"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/startup.htm#BABGDACG) in Database Concepts), and the next time it's started the crash recovery will be automatically performed which may take some amount of time.

Sometimes Transactional Mode shutdown may be faster than the shutdown with Immediate Mode since Immediate Mode shutdown rolls back all transactions that were running when the shutdown was initiated, and if some DML had already updated millions of rows, committing it would be faster than rolling it back, because most of the changes are already in the redo log and in data files.

Comment: @Mat Okay, I will not believe blindly in the documents anymore. I will not believe blindly in the documents anymore. I will not believe blindly in the documents anymore. I will not believe blindly in the documents anymore... (:

Comment: @Mat I need to test it to improve the answer, or you can edit it, because you have more experience (:

Comment: Actually I'm having doubts about the immediate case... seems like it should timeout too (really hard to test though :-)). Replace "may take up to an hour" by "may timeout after an hour" and your answer should be correct. (After a shutdown timeout the database isn't shut down.)